# How can I put values of a charline in y axis?

Tags: linechart

How can I put just the values of my linechart in the y axis?

The values are 22,21,23,25,19. And I want to show all the values in y axis, not only 20,25.

My linechart looks like this,

[image]

And I want to show values in y axis, like that,

[image]

Comment: Please give more information about which programming language / component you are using.

Comment: This is a linechart in jasperreport